# Datetime conversation in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have an api, which has java `DateTime` type, which returns the following hash:

```
{"Date":1403592945000}
```

The actual date value is: `"2014-06-24 06:55:45"`. How do I convert it in Ruby?

Comment: The question is not clear. Isn't `"2014-06-24 06:55:45"` a Ruby string? What do you mean by "convert it in Ruby"? Do you mean to convert a string **into a date object** within Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Time.at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Time.html#method-c-at) is the function you want to use. However, it seems that your value also contains milliseconds, that in Ruby should passed apart.

```
Time.at(1403592945000) # wrong
Time.at(1403592945) # => 2014-06-24 08:55:45 +0200
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Time.at(hash['Date']/1000)
```

Comment: or `1000.0` if you want to keep the milliseconds